# Сохранение большого по размеру изображения с canvas?

Tags: jquery, canvas, javascript, изображения, html5

Имеется js скрипт загрузки и манипуляции изображением с использованием библиотеки fabricjs. Размеры канвы 600x350 пикселей. Если в канву загружаю изображение меньших размеров и после сохраняю с канвы в файл на диск компьютера, то все нормально. Но когда загружаю изображение в канву больше, чем размер канвы (viewport), и после сохраняю файл на диск, то изображение почему-то кропается до размеров канвы.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сохранять с канвы изображение, которое имеет большие размеры, чем размер канвы?

Answer (score 2):

Разместите элемент canvas в div со с атрибутом `style="overflow: hidden;"` и фиксированным размером, когда как сам canvas можно будет подгонять по размеру под конкретное изображение каждый раз.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, создать еще невидимый большого размера канвас и на уровни JS над ним осуществлять те же действия, которые осуществляются над основным и затем, непосредственно, сохранять изображения с невидимого канваса.